# accessing Inner class while creating BitmapField & adding it in HorizontalFieldManager

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I'm creating a inner class in a method. After that I am accessing some statements like,

```
public class Test extends MainScreen
{
  HorizontalFieldManager hfm;
  Bitmap bitmap[] = new Bitmap[100];
  BitmapField[] bitmapField = new BitmapField[100];
  int countBitmap = 0;

  Test()
  {
      VerticalFieldManager vfm_Main = new VerticalFieldManager();
      hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
      vfm_Main.add(hfm);
      add(vfm_Main); 
  }


  void drawBitmap()
  {
     bitmap[countBitmap] = new Bitmap(100, 100);
     bitmapField[countBitmap] = new BitmapField(bitmap[countBitmap]){
     public void paint(Graphics g)
     {
           ................
           ................
           g.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);
      }
   }


   synchronized(UiApplication.getEventLock())
   {

      for(int i = 0 ; i < bitmapField.length; i++)
      {
         if(bitmapField[i] != null)
         {
              bitmapField[i].setBitmap(bitmap[i]);
         }
      }
        hfm.add(bitmapField[countBitmap]);  
        countBitmap++;
```

But here the problem is after creating the bitmap & before creating the bitmapField, control goes to

```
synchronized(UiApplication.getEventLock()){hfm.add(bitmapField[countBitmap]); }
```

So before creating the bitmapField, it adds it in hfm.

So the output is coming like "Everytime a new BitmapField is added in hfm (means at the same position by replacing the previous one)". But I want the BitmapFields come next to each other in hfm.

How to do it?

Any solution why the control goes first to hfm.add()  before the new bitmapField() inner class?

Comment: Your coding style here seems uneven, and there appear to be some close parenthesis missing. Makes it a bit difficult to understand what you are trying to do here. For example, where does the second snipped of code fit in? Is it the end of drawBitmap()?

Comment: The replacing issue (replacing at the same position by replacing the previous one)is solved now. But a new issue is that the recent drawing is added by replacing the previous one.

Means if u draw for the first time then it comes properly in bitmapField. if u draw for second time then 2 times the 2nd drawing is added in bitmapField by replacing the previous one.

paint() is called 2 times to draw 2 drawings.

 
 How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, several suggestions about code:

- see no reason using synchronized since it's UI thread
- don't setBitmap, bitmap is already passed to BitmapField constructor
- actually all BitmapFields come next to each other in hfm, to make it clear, I've add number to each one.
- if you want some custom constructor or new fields in BitmapField, it's better to create new class as an extension of BitmapField

  ```
  class TestScr extends MainScreen {
  HorizontalFieldManager hfm;
  Bitmap bitmap[] = new Bitmap[100];
  BitmapField[] bitmapField = new BitmapField[100];

  TestScr() {
      hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager();
      add(hfm);
      drawBitmap();
  }

  void drawBitmap() {
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          bitmap[i] = new Bitmap(50, 50);

          Graphics graphics = new Graphics(bitmap[i]);
          graphics.setColor(Color.RED);
          String number = Integer.toString(i);
          Font font = graphics.getFont().derive(Font.BOLD, 40, Ui.UNITS_px);
          graphics.setFont(font);
          int textWidth = graphics.getFont().getAdvance(number);
          int textHeight = graphics.getFont().getHeight();
          int x = (bitmap[i].getWidth() - textWidth) / 2;
          int y = (bitmap[i].getHeight() - textHeight) / 2;
          graphics.drawText(number, x, y);

          bitmapField[i] = new BitmapField(bitmap[i]) {
              public void paint(Graphics g) {
                  super.paint(g);
                  int width = getWidth() - 1;
                  int height = getHeight() - 1;
                  g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                  g.drawLine(0, 0, width, 0);
                  g.drawLine(width, 0, width, height);
                  g.drawLine(width, height, 0, height);
                  g.drawLine(0, height, 0, 0);
              }
          };

          hfm.add(bitmapField[i]);
      }
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: Hi coldice, first of all thx a lot for the answer. Now its coming next to each other. See my answer also. I was trying this for 3 days. Thanks a lot......